# Correlated subquery display count column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following query which works fine:

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_type_cd, c.city, count(*) as `count`
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN account a
    ON a.cust_id = c.cust_id
GROUP BY c.cust_id
HAVING `count` = 2;
```

Result:

```
+---------+--------------+---------+-------+
| cust_id | cust_type_cd | city    | count |
+---------+--------------+---------+-------+
|       2 | I            | Woburn  |     2 |
|       3 | I            | Quincy  |     2 |
|       6 | I            | Waltham |     2 |
|       8 | I            | Salem   |     2 |
|      10 | B            | Salem   |     2 |
+---------+--------------+---------+-------+
```

I would like to achieve the same result using a correlated subquery. I have not been able to make a "count" column as show above:

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_type_cd, c.city
FROM customer c
WHERE 2 = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM account a
    WHERE a.cust_id = c.cust_id
);
```

Result:

```
+---------+--------------+---------+
| cust_id | cust_type_cd | city    |
+---------+--------------+---------+
|       2 | I            | Woburn  |
|       3 | I            | Quincy  |
|       6 | I            | Waltham |
|       8 | I            | Salem   |
|      10 | B            | Salem   |
+---------+--------------+---------+
```

How can I achieve the same result as the one using the INNER JOIN and have a "count" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you wanted this but you also need to specify the subquery in the `SELECT` part,

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_type_cd, c.city, (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                              FROM account a
                                              WHERE a.cust_id = c.cust_id) AS `count`
FROM customer c
WHERE 2 = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM account a
    WHERE a.cust_id = c.cust_id
);
```

Comment: it's just an exercise, in finding different ways to achieve things.

Comment: Wow. That does look a little messy compared to the INNER JOIN.

Comment: @RobertRocha exactly.